# Does Windows Datacenter Edition get patched centrally

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-update, datacenter

I'm running an Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 Datacenter Edition instance. I tried to run Windows update on it a couple of times but it just seems to hang. Does the Datacenter edition get patched centrally somehow or do I still need to patch my individual instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No

You have to patch them yourselves. I don't think the hanging is related to EC2. Is there anything in the error logs (`eventvwr`)?

Comment: I didn't look into it too deeply. It's a micro instance so everything is very very slow. Instead of patching I ended up creating a new instance based on Amazon's latest image. Hopefully it's patched.

Comment: "Hopefully" - as in, Hopefully you'll actually check it's patched.